# Can you use = and == together in the same script?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, comparison, equals

Had some problems with a script running, which was mainly built around dropdown menus. Single equals = and exactly equals == were both used in the same function, though not same if statement. Could not see anything else amiss and made all uses ==, which seemed to resolve problem. I'm relatively new to Javascript, so was just wondering if combining different styles of equals makes a difference was all. Didn't think it did.

Comment: Do you mean `==` vs `===`?

Comment: Can you show us the offending code, please?

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator used to assign values to variable and `==` is a comparison operator used to determine equality or difference between variables or values. They have totally different uses.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't really make sense - these are different operators. In javascript:

```
= is the assignment operator, e.g.

var x = 1;

if (x = 1) // This would not compare x to 1, it would assign the value 1 to x
           // and then return the value to the if block which would decide
           // whether the value is truthy or not (and in this case 
           // return true).

== is the comparison operator, e.g.

var x == 1;  //This would not make sense (or run)

if (x == 1) { 

=== does a comparison and ensures that both operands are the same type:

var x = "1";

if (x == 1) { //Returns true

if (x === 1) //returns false.
```

Comment: `if ( x = 1 )` will both set x to 1 and return 1, causing the if-statement to always pass as true in its comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`=` *assigns* values to variables.
`==` and `===` are *comparison* operators.

Of course your script logic changes quite a bit when you exchange `=` and `==` operators.

Comment: Yeah, think that was the problem. The piece of script was basically an edit to something written by a colleague and looked like this if(TotPerAmt==TotLateYTD)
     {
      $('.dcTell1').show();
      $('.dcTell2').hide();
      $('.dcTell3').hide();
     }
   
    else if((TotEYTD+TotPerAmt)=TotLateYTD)
     {
      $('.dcTell1').hide();
      $('.dcTell2').show();
      $('.dcTell3').hide();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.dcTell1').hide();
      $('.dcTell2').hide();
      $('.dcTell3').show();
   
     }

Comment: Excuse the mess with the paste there. when i made the single = in the else if ((TotEYTD into ==, the thing worked. Before, was returning error cannot assign Nan to Number. As I say, still new to this, cheers for comments.